# Java: Thread local memory allocation and scalability

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-management, scalability

I am trying to improve scalability of a java application which processes a number of small tasks in separate threads. But it shows unexpectedly poor results. It seems that memory allocations is not scallable at all. That is strange, as objects are allocated locally for each thread. Java memory manager should be able to allocate them in thread's local heap without global locking. GC thread do not show any significant activity.
There is a simple test:

```
private static class AllocTest implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
        {
            char[] s = new char[100];
        }
    }
}

final int THREADS_COUNT = 4;
    LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> taskQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(THREADS_COUNT);
    ThreadFactory threadFactory = Executors.defaultThreadFactory();
    ThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(THREADS_COUNT, THREADS_COUNT, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS, taskQueue, threadFactory);
    pool.prestartAllCoreThreads();

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
        pool.getQueue().offer(new AllocTest(), 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
    pool.shutdown();
    pool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.print("Elapsed time: ");
    System.out.print(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(endTime - startTime));
```

Changing threads count (THREADS_COUNT) from 1 to 4, I get nearly the same results:
THREADS_COUNT Time

1. 4811
2. 4783
3. 4814
4. 4823

The test is run using "-server" VM flag.
Java version - 1.8.0_66.
Tried on platforms - Windows 7 x64 (1 processor, 8 cores), SunOS 5.10 x64 (2 processors, 8 cores).

I would appreciate any explanation of such behavior or suggestions on what can be done to get better scalability (e.g. some specific jvm settings).

Edit: I understand that introducing some thread local pool to reuse Objects instead of allocating it each time should improve scalability. But it is just workaround (which I am currently trying to implement). I actually would like to find an answer on these two questions: 1) why provided test is not scallable? and 2) if it is not hardware limitation, how to make jvm work efficiently in such case without code changes?

Comment: Are you sure the memory is allocated from the heap at all? With such overly simple code the Java compiler should be able to figure out that the memory can be allocated from the stack or even not at all.

Comment: I think in such case "Elapsed time" would be nearly 0

Comment: @james large OK, but there is at least such thing as TLAB: Thread-local allocation buffer. Used to allocate heap space quickly without synchronization

Comment: Point taken.    Comment withdrawn.

Comment: @VladimirP: Hm just noticed that it's taking a fair time (4.8s) to do whatever it's doing, so it must be doing something. I've deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like allocation speed was pretty close to the theoretical maximum for my RAM. Java reached it even in 1 thread, so it was not any better with more threads. Also, I found that my PC was configured to work with memory in Single channel mode (two RAM modules were installed to slots of different color). In Dual mode I observe twice better results.

P.S. Thanks everyone for your ideas!